# How to use the animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm just beginner for JavaScript, but I try to do some function and I follow some guy on the internet

I'm trying to do Hide and Show the Menu.

My purpose is When I move my mouse to the Menu, it will show from bottom to up and when I move my mouse to outside it will be move slowly from up to bottom. 
I can do with Click Function, but When I try with movemouse and mouseleave, it can not work.

I create 2 function

```
function showSelect() {
    $("#select").animate({"bottom": 0}, 300, 'linear');
}
function hideSelect() {
    $("#select").animate({"bottom": -148}, 300, 'linear');
}
```

And this code move my mouse :

```
$("#select").mousemove(function() {
    $("#select").showSelect();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $("select").hideSelect();  
});
```

I hope some one can give me some advices. Thanks

Comment: "it can not work" please explain what the issues is so people can help. also, seen as someone else will say it anyway java != javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mw2fv1d2/2/)

You need to apply following code

```
$( "#select" ).mouseout(function() {
 $("#select").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
    borderWidth: "10px"
  }, 1500 );
  });
  $( "#select" ).mouseover(function() {
 $("#select").animate({
    width: "90%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
    borderWidth: "10px"
  }, 1500 );
  });
```

Comment: I saw your code, but when I move my mouse outside, it not smaller.

Comment: I have decreased width by 70% you can reduce the parameter as needed

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function as you're already binding element in that function to animate:

```
    //$("#select").showSelect();
    showSelect();
```

As per your requirement, I think you need mouseenter and mouseleave:

```
$('#select').mouseenter(function() {
    showSelect();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    hideSelect();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hei guy, try this:

```
$('#select').hover(function (){
    // when mouse hover
    showSelect();
}, function (){
    // when mouse out
    hideSelect();
});
```